# Extend class in third party definition file

Tags: typescript

I provide a typescript definition file for a non-ts library I've written. My library extends `EventEmitter2` as a "native" event system so I'm trying to determine how to define that:

```
/// <reference types="eventemitter2" />

declare module "my-module" {
  class MyClass extends EventEmitter2 {
    // ...
  }
}
```

... which doesn't work. EventEmitter2 provides a `d.ts` file so it should be available, but the error I get is:

`Cannot find name 'EventEmitter2'`

I don't work with ts enough to know where I'm going wrong. I've tried reading docs/looking for examples but nothing seems to address this type of issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using a triple-slash directive, you can import the type declarations from `eventemitter2`:

```ts
import { EventEmitter2 } from 'eventemitter2';

declare module "my-module" {
  class MyClass extends EventEmitter2 {
    // ...
  }
}
```

The triple-slash directive does not work because the `.d.ts` file is in the module itself and is not under `node_modules/@types`.

Comment: I had tried a different `import` but this works. Thanks! Now that I think about it though, wouldn't this require that my library have a peer dependency in order for this to compile for end users? That won't work, so I may need to manually include the relevant methods.

Comment: Yes, you'll need it as a dependency. It's not clear why you need to use the `eventemitter2` types if you are not already using `eventemitter2` - in which case, you'd already be dependent.

Comment: My library uses eventemitter2 internally to provide an events API rather than reinventing the wheel, so it's a development dep. For those using the UMD/bundled version of my library they won't have any of the dev deps installed.

Comment: I see. I distribute my packages with UMD bundles, too - in addition to separate `.js` and `.d.ts` files. And both use the same type declarations. I guess you have to consider whether or not taking `eventemitter2` as a non-dev dependency (for the typings) is acceptable.